# Python - PysimpleGUI

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I have a GUI using PySimpleGUI.
I select a folder and want to display the files' names inside that folder in a Table element.

If there is a file with a space in its name, let's say "Fonzy Cunningham", it will appear as "{Fonzy Cunningham}" (files' names are loaded using the os library).

Adding "FonzyCunningham.cool" and then "Fonzy Cunningham.cool", the one with space in that string will be displayed with {} like "{Fonzy Cunningham.cool}" so not so cool.
I would like to get "FonzyCunningham.cool" and on the second row "Fonzy Cunnigham.cool" withouht those "{" or "}".

Edit:
I am adding a sample source code to reproduce the problem

```
import PySimpleGUI as Sg

fake_init_data = []
results_table_headings = ["First Column", "Second Column"]
results_table_layout = [[Sg.Table(values=fake_init_data[:][:],
                                  headings=results_table_headings,
                                  auto_size_columns=False,
                                  justification='left',
                                  num_rows=5,
                                  key="results_table",
                                  row_height=20,
                                  col_widths=[30, 30],
                                  enable_events=True)]]

window = Sg.Window("Version .1.0", results_table_layout, finalize=True)

ui_results_table = window["results_table"]
pdf_results = [[['Fonzy Cunningham.cool'], ["HighFive"]],
               [['FonzyCunningham.cool'], ["High Six"]]]
row_colors = [[0, "#64778D"], [1, "#64778D"]]

ui_results_table.update(values=pdf_results, row_colors=row_colors)

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=1)

    if event != "__TIMEOUT__" and event is not None:
        print("##################################################")
        print(f"EVENT = {event}")

    if event == Sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
```

The results I am getting is:
[image: PySimpleGUI]

I don't understand why those "{", "}" are added whenever there is a space in the string.

Please help.

Comment: Add your code with what example value for the Table element. Most of time, it is caused by the wrong format of the data for the Table element and it should be a list of lists of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the format of the data as Jason Yang mentioned.
Instead of:

```
pdf_results = [[['Fonzy Cunningham.cool'], ["HighFive"]], 
               [['FonzyCunningham.cool'], ["High Six"]]]
```

It should be:

```
pdf_results = [["Fonzy Cunningham.cool", "HighFive"],
               ["FonzyCunningham.cool", "High Six"]]
```

This gives the expected result:

[image: Correct result]